# nodejs error on es6 class constructor with default parameter value

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, class, ecmascript-6

I am run simple es6 class code as the following:

```
'use strict';
class Polygon {
  constructor(height=44, width=55) { //class constructor
    this.name = 'Polygon';
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  sayName() { //class method
    console.log('Hi, I am a', this.name + '.');
   }
}

class Square extends Polygon {
  constructor(length) {
    super(length, length); //call the parent method with super
    this.name = 'Square';
  }

  get area() { //calculated attribute getter
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}

let s = new Square();

 s.sayName();
 console.log(s.area);
```

It is running ok on chrome console. 
But it is running errors on nodejs(4.x, 5.x) as the following:

```
constructor(height=44, width=55) { //class constructor
                      ^

  SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
  at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
  at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
  at startup (node.js:148:18)
  at node.js:405:3
```

I think es6 do support default parameters for function, and chrome and node.js are run V8 engine, why do give out diff answer,...

Answer (score 3):

This is an `in progress` feature in 5.x which can be activated by the flag `--harmony_default_parameters`:

```
$ node -v 
v5.0.0
$ node --harmony_default_parameters  script.js
```

To see a list of in progress flags in your node version:

```
node --v8-options | grep "in progress"
```

Comment: hassansin: Thanks, It works,...But it is only on v5.x, and it is not long stable version, production can't use it, 4.x doesn't have this option,...

Comment: Yup, not all version have this flag. Depends on which v8 engine it's using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Babel` to transpile your code like this:

1. `npm init`
2. `npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-stage-2`
3. modify `package.json` so that it will contain the following script:

   {
     "scripts": {
       "start": "babel-node script.js --presets es2015,stage-2"
     }
   }
4. execute the script `npm run start`. It will output `Hi, I am a Square. 2420`